# Build android source in user mode

Tags: android

I want to build the android sdk  in user mode .Could any one guide me in this.Please tell me the steps in achieving this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building an Android Source Code is some complex task. You have to first Initializing a Build Environment for that. And after Choosing a Branch for your requirement.

I suggest you to build android source code on Linux machine specially, **ubuntu 10.04**.
As Android Platform support officially on this.

*Note: The source download is approximately 6GB in size. You will need 25GB free to complete a single build, and up to 90GB (or more) for a full set of builds.*

You can find further instruction on this [Initializing a Build Environment](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html)

**Update:**

Also Look at [How to Compile ICS (Ubuntu)](http://www.freeyourandroid.com/guide/compile-ics) and [How to Compile Android from Source Code](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/how-to-compile-android-from-source-code-xda-tv/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+xda-developers%2FShsH+%28xda-developers%29&utm_content=Google+International)

Develop an sdk in user mode, Use this command

```
$ lunch full-user
```

limited access; suited for production

**Also other Target (developing modes)**

```
$ lunch full-userdebug
```

like "user" but with root access and debuggability; preferred for debugging

```
$ lunch full-eng
```

development configuration with additional debugging tools

Comment: Thank you very much for the info ..I want to know how to build for user mode i.e., we have 3 build types-user,userdebug,eng..how to do this for a device ..I want to develop an sdk in user mode and deploy it in a device